# Lifetime of variable in map/flat_map in Rust

Tags: rust

I think I have a good understanding of lifetimes, but what I've read doesn't tick with what the compiler says when it comes to closures ;)

I have a function with the signature:

```
fn split_to_words(content: &str) -> Vec<String>
```

With `for` loops it looks like this:

```
let mut acc: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
for line in content.lines() {
    if line.is_empty() { continue };
    for word in line.split_whitespace() {
        acc.push(word.to_lowercase());
    }
}
```

and using iterators:

```
let acc: Vec<String> = content.lines()
      .filter(|x| !x.is_empty())
      .map(|x| x.to_lowercase())
      .flat_map(|x: String| x.split_whitespace())
      .map(|x| x.to_string())
      .collect();
```

but I end up with an error:

```
error: `x` does not live long enough

.flat_map(|x: String| x.split_whitespace())
                      ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your iterator-style code isn't exactly the same as your imperative-style code: in the imperative code, you do `split_whitespace` before `to_lowercase`, whereas in the iterator code, you do the opposite. It turns out that doing `split_whitespace` before is more efficient, since `split_whitespace` doesn't need to allocate `Strings`; it only returns slices into the given string slice. On the other hand, `to_lowercase` needs to allocate a new string, so by doing it last, we can save an allocation.

```
let acc: Vec<String> = content.lines()
      .filter(|x| !x.is_empty())
      .flat_map(|x| x.split_whitespace())
      .map(|x| x.to_lowercase())
      .collect();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's helpful to review the entire error message:

```
error: `x` does not live long enough
note: reference must be valid for the method call at ...
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the scope
      of parameters for function at ...
```

When `flat_map` is called, you **pass ownership** of the `String` to the closure. However, the closure tries to return an iterator that contains references to the `String`. Since each `String` will be deallocated after the closure call ends, the reference into it would be invalid, so the compiler prevents you from doing this.

I'd probably use the `for`-loop variant or a similar version:

```
fn split_to_words(content: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let lines = content.lines()
           .filter(|x| !x.is_empty())
           .map(|x| x.to_lowercase());

    let mut result = Vec::new();

    for line in lines {
        for word in line.split_whitespace() {
            result.push(word.to_string());
        }
    }

    result
}

fn main() -> () {
    println!("{:?}", split_to_words("hello world"));
}
```

In *this* particular case though, I think you could write it as:

```
fn split_to_words(content: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    content.split_whitespace().map(str::to_lowercase).collect()
}
```

Newlines **are** whitespace, so there's no need to use `lines`. This also removes the possibility of blank values.

Comment: I didn't know about `str::to_lowercase`, it looks similar to how it is done in Java. Thx for that! I was thinking that it would be nice to have it work that way!