# Rust flat_map with temporary local

Tags: rust

Let's assume a function that converts a string into another string:

```
fn foo(s: &str) -> String {
    s.to_owned() + "\nsomething"
}
```

Can I convert the following loops

```
fn main() {
    let a = [String::from("multi\nline")].to_vec();
    for s in a {
        for l in foo(&s).lines() {
            println!("{}", l);
        }
    }
}
```

into something using iterators like this?

```
fn main() {
    let a = [String::from("multi\nline")].to_vec();
    a.iter()
        .flat_map(|s| foo(&s).lines())
        .for_each(|l| println!("{}", l));
}
```

Currently this runs (understandably) into a lifetime issue:

```
8 |         .flat_map(|s| foo(&s).lines())
  |                       -------^^^^^^^^
  |                       |
  |                       returns a reference to data owned by the current function
  |                       temporary value created here
  |
  = help: use `.collect()` to allocate the iterator
```

While there are similar questions already raised [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146040/flat-map-with-a-nested-iterator-in-rust)] [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967681/lifetime-of-variable-in-map-flat-map-in-rust)], none of them directly answer my question.

How do I get the iterator-style snippet working? Are my only options the following?

- Allocate/materialize the iterator in flat_map (less efficient)
- Implement a struct adhering to the Iterator trait that takes ownership of the temporary String
- Stick with the imperative loops

Comment: Do you want to consume vector or not? Because in the loop example you are consuming it and in iterator you are just borrowing it. Which way you want it to be?

Comment: The problem is not only `flat_map` but `lines()`, too; it works with references and not owned strings.

Comment: `collect`ing as `owned` String first and then `for_each`  can resolve your problem.  i.e.  `a.iter().flat_map(|s| foo(&s).lines().map(|x| x.to_owned()).collect::<Vec<_>>()).for_each(|l| println!("{}", l));`  But I don't know if there is better solution.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze, you are right. That is inconsistent in my example. But I think it does not matter for the temporary in the `flat_map`. Does it?

Comment: @xcwang Indeed. That is what I meant by the first bullet point. I was hoping that there is a shorter / more idiomatic approach that would also prevent the separate allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not only `flat_map` but `lines()`, too; it references the strings which get dropped by the end of the closure.

```rust
fn foo(s: &str) -> String {
    s.to_owned() + "\nsomething"
}

fn main() {
    let a = [String::from("multi\nline")].to_vec();
    a.iter()
        .flat_map(|s| foo(&s).lines().map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect::<Vec<_>>())
        .for_each(|s| println!("{}", s));
}
```

In this small example you have given, the `for_each` can be skipped and the code can be put into the `flat_map`.

Depending on the context I think the imperative loop is even easier to understand.

Comment: So then the solution is indeed to allocate a vector and thereby materialize the `lines()` iterator. I was hoping that there is a way to "extend" the lifetime of the string and then iterate over the line-by-line slices. With the explicit `collect`, I am copying the string (or the lines of it) again.
In fairness, though: I measured both approaches in my actual program and there is no discernible difference. This really is a question of style.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `for_each` inside the closure of `flat_map` can resolve your problem, since by doing this, the lifetime of the return String of `foo(&s)` can outlive  `for_each`.

Here is the code

```
fn foo(s: &str) -> String {
    s.to_owned() + "\nsomething"
}

fn main() {
    let a = [String::from("multi\nline")].to_vec();
    let b = a.into_iter();
    b.flat_map(|s| {
        foo(&s).lines().for_each(|l| println!("{}", l));
        std::iter::Empty::<()>::default()                    // generate an Empty  
    })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
}
```

Note the line where an `Empty` is generated, this is because `flat_map()` requires `f` 's return type `U` to implement `IntoIterator`, i.e.

```
fn flat_map<U, F>(self, f: F) -> FlatMap<Self, U, F>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        U: IntoIterator,
        F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> U,
    {
        FlatMap::new(self, f)
    }
```